# i want to push arrays into array

Tags: javascript, arrays

i have two parameters & two arguments, one of them should be a number & the other should be array, if the number hs similar items in the array i should extract the similar numbers then push them again into the array, with keeping the order of non-similar numbers, i have wrote this code but its not working, i spent more than two days trying to figure this out but no result yet.

```
function extractNumber(num, nums) {
if(nums.includes(num)===true){
  for (let i = 0; i <nums.length; i++) {
    if(nums[i]=== num){
     var popped = nums.splice(i,1);
      i--;
      nums.push(popped);
    } 
  }  
}
  return nums;
}

extractNumber(7,   [1,2,7,1,7,1,7,3,7,1]);
```

Comment: For starters, what language is this?

Comment: this is javascript.

Comment: What is the "word array"?

Comment: Please remove the all caps from the title

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this ?

Your title is a bit misleading.

```js
function extractNumber(num, nums) {
  nums.forEach((i, index) => { //loop each item in nums
    if (i === num) { //if current item is same as num
      nums.splice(index, 1) //remove it from its position..
      nums.push(i) //..and push it at the end of the array
    }
  })
  return nums
}


console.log(extractNumber(7, [1, 2, 7, 1, 7, 1, 7, 3, 7, 1]))
```

Comment: it worked, thanks a lot, but can you please explain the forEach part, because i did not understand it, it is a little bit vague for me.

Comment: @فراسالحمدان Array.forEach goes through each item of an array,and runs a function for every item,giving 2 parameters,its value and its index/position within the array(i is the value in my example) . here it explains it better,and generally google and read documentation for every programming-related topic - - > https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_foreach.asp

Comment: also,comments in my code explain step by step

Answer (score 0):

I think your code has just a few issues:

- instead of `Array#push`ing `popped`, an array, push `num` instead.
- no need for `i--` as that's not necessary.

I like your approach in that you avoid unnecessary looping if `num` is not an element of the array. So your corrected code looks like so:

```js
function extractNumber(num, nums) {
  if( nums.includes(num) ) {
    for (let i = 0; i <nums.length; i++) {
      if(nums[i] === num){
        nums.splice(i,1);
        nums.push(num);
      } 
    }  
  }
  return nums;
}

console.log( extractNumber(7,   [1,2,7,1,7,1,7,3,7,1]) );
```

**Another Approach**

As indicated in the comments, there are issues with this approach. We can:

- Find all the elements that aren't equal to `num` using `Array#filter`.
- Then `push` `num` as many times as the number of elements in the result is less than `nums`.

```js
function extractNumber(num, nums) {
  const notnum = nums.filter(n => n !== num);
  notnum.push(...Array(nums.length - notnum.length).fill(num) );
  return notnum;
}

console.log( extractNumber(7,   [1,2,7,1,7,1,7,3,7,1]) );
console.log( extractNumber(17,   [1,5,4,17,17,9,17]) );
console.log( extractNumber(6,   [1,2,7,1,7,1,7,3,7,1]) );
```

Comment: this code works well if i have no repitition in the array, for example if i have an array =[1,5,4,17,17,9,17], it will loop through the array, will splice th first and second '17', then will stop, for unknown reason to me for now, that why i used the i--, and it was by mistake to be honest, but it worked, but once i wanted to push the spliced numbers again it will push the arrays as arrays not hte values of the arrays, or it will loop for ever,

Comment: I now see exactly what you mean; it's never a good idea to change the number of elements or index of the array being looped through. Let's have a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you want something like this

```
function extractNumber(num, nums) {
 const matrixFix = nums.reduce((acc, cv) => {
  if (num !== cv) {
   return { notSimilar: [...acc.notSimilar, cv], similar: [...acc.similar] }
  };
  return { notSimilar: [...acc.notSimilar], similar: [...acc.similar, cv] 
  };
 }, { similar: [], notSimilar: [] })

 return [...matrixFix.notSimilar, ...matrixFix.similar];
}

extractNumber(7,   [1, 2, 7, 1, 7, 1, 7, 3, 7, 1]);
```